# How can we figure out the image of exponential function?

Tags: exponential-function

I definitely think of this question as a very fundamental one.
But I'd like to figure out what the image of exp is in general.

Given a polynomial function $f(x)$, how can we determine the image( plot, precisely) of

$\exp({f(x)})$??

---

Thanks to two earlier comments.
I append more details what i want:
According to your explanations, we can find out just the range.
What about the shape of exp(f(x))??

Comment: If you want to see it, graph it once.  They all look the same. (I always thought they look like slugs.)  If you want to "get" them ... well there's a lot to say, mainly because the are their own derivatives.  They are convex smooth and scalable.

Comment: Oh, "image" in the mathematical sense! The range that is strictly mapped to.  It's (0,infinity).  If b>0, b!= 1 then b^x is always positive, asymptotic to zero in one direction and unbounded in the other.

Answer (score 2):

I presume you are talking about real numbers.  Find the image of $f$.  If that is $[a,\infty)$, then the image of $\exp(f)$ is $[\exp(a),\infty)$.  If it is $(-\infty, b]$, then $(0, \exp(b)]$.  If it is $(-\infty, \infty)$, then $(0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to determine the range of $f(x)$, which is of one of the forms $(-\infty,a]$, $[b,+\infty)$ or $(-\infty,+\infty)$. Then the range of $\exp(f(x))$ will be $(0,e^a]$, $[e^b,+\infty)$ or $(0,+\infty)$, accordingly.